# I am confused which articles will be used in the questions mentioned below

Tags: grammar, articles, definite-articles, indefinite-articles

- I have done __ MBA in marketing from __ IIM.
- I have done __ MBA in marketing from __ Indian Institute of Management.

---

Options....

- An
- A
- The
- No article

Comment: @KannE..don't we need to use 'an' before IIM?

Comment: @user369182: we would only use *an IIM* if there was more than one IIM.  Otherwise it would be *the IIM* or, in some contexts plain *IIM*.  How many IIMs are there ?

Answer (score 0):

> I have done **my** MBA in marketing from IIM
>
> I have done **my** MBA in marketing from the Indian Institute of Management

These are the ways I would write.
 
Explanation 1: I have written ***MY*** before MBA as it was done by me so it is a matter of pride. MBA is a degree and not any rank soo one should answer the subjective questions of whose MBA, Which MBA and What MBA to include in the statement.
Explanation 2: In the first sentence I have not used any article as IIM, as it is a short form of the Indian Institute of Management. That is the reason why I added the ***THE*** to state the Indian Institute of Management in the second sentence.

Hope this helps

Comment: **Why** did you decide on that? Please [edit your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/525615/edit) to include that. Explaining will help the OP in future cases.

Answer (score 0):

> I have done an MBA in marketing from IIM.
>
> I have done an MBA in marketing from the Indian Institute of
>   Management.

I think these are proper variants

Comment: **Why** did you decide on that? Please [edit your answer](https://english.stackexchange.com/posts/525648/edit) to include that. Explaining will help the OP in future cases.